# Mongo / Mongoose : How to access a dynamic prop inside an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using the $in operator inside a condition, but it only works if I hard code the property im searching for. Im not sure how to do it if the property is dynamic (i am iterating over an object where the value of key is an array with objects. Any help would be great. Thanks!! Ps. I didnt add to much code as I thoguht its not relevant, hapy to add more of course should be relevant.

my record:

```
{
name: "product1",
reports: [{propToGet: '...', ...}, {}],
...
}
```

I want to add more records under certain conditions:

```
const reports = {prop1: [{propToGet: '...'}, {propToGet: '...'}], prop2: [{}], ...}
await Product.findOneAndUpdate({
....

 for (let key in reports) {
  ....
  "$cond": [
             {
               "$in": [
                  [reports[key].map(function(x) {
                        return new Date(x.propToGet)
                   }), //if propToGet isnt same for same product, dont add
                   "$reports.propToGet"
                ]

              },
...
}
```

EDIT: detailed code

```
scrape: async (reports) => {
    for (let key in reports) {
        await Product.findOneAndUpdate({"name": key},
            [
                {
                    "$set": {
                        "reports": {
                            "$cond": [
                                {
                                    "$in": [
                                        reports[key].map(function(x) {
                                                console.log("whyy", )
                                                return x.dateTime
                                            }
                                        ),
                                        "$reports.dateTime"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "$reports",
                                {
                                    "$concatArrays": [
                                        "$reports",
                                        reports[key]
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ], {new: true})
    };
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [arrayFilter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#definition)

and its better to keep the `Query` only doing query, any looping condition should be outside of the `query`

```
await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
   { $set: { "prop.$[elem].propToGet" : '...' } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.propToGet": '...' } ] }
)
```

updated answer as another solution:,

```
scrape: async (reports) => {
    for (let key in reports) {
        const condition = reports[key].map((x) => {
            console.log('whyy');
            return x.dateTime;
        });

        await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                name: key,
                reports: {
                    $in: condition
                }
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    reports: {
                        $concatArrays: ['$reports', reports[key]]
                    }
                }
            },
            { upsert: true }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: nothing is happening with it, nothing is added to the db in any case.

Comment: @juliascoding which version mongodb you are using? and maybe you can add more detail on your case

Comment: to filter data array in Mongodb like in the case, you can simply do query like:  `{"prop.propToGet": {$in: ['...']}}`

Comment: I am doing a query with $in but its not working, thus my question. i can update my code with more details

Comment: i update my answer, and i change the `options` to be `{ upsert: true }`. i hope that the answer you are looking for.

Comment: and you can change the `$set` to use `$push`. i think you are tryng to update a part of the array data in database without changing the existing data. i hope that the answer you are looking for.

Comment: its unfortunately not working. if there is no report with said property thats same (dateTime), nothing is still being added to the db

Comment: oh now I notice: it checks for when there is the dateTime value in reports, only then its suppose to push based on the code but its suppose to be the other way around: only add new reports to the reports array, if there is NOT same value in dateTime

Comment: yes, it will be add a new record to db because we are using option `upsert: true`. it means that if data not found, data will added.  I think the code above should be works, just change the `upsert: false`

Comment: if I say upsert false then nothing will be added in any case. if i set it to true, I get an error saying:  The field 'reports' must be an array but is of type string in document {no id}

Comment: thats correct, thats why you need to move the loop outside of the query, and then you can check `if (reports.length > 0){do query}`. its your requirment when you put `//if propToGet isnt same for same product, dont add`

Comment: no its the opposite, if i have a report with same value for said property then DONT add. sorry, i must have mixed it up. the loop is outside the query like in the code